# Does ARMv8's ret clear the nzvc register?

Tags: arm64, armv8

Does ARMv8's `ret` instruction clear the `nzvc` register?

From [the document](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2022-12/Base-Instructions/RET--Return-from-subroutine-?lang=en) I couldn't find it, but compiling a code that does 192-bit integer addition using llc-14 sets the flag using `adcs`: https://godbolt.org/z/zWo6GKsE7

Answer (score 0):

No. `ret` does nothing except branch to `x30` (or whatever other register you pass it).

The manual defines its operation as:

```
bits(64) target = X[n, 64];
// Value in BTypeNext will be used to set PSTATE.BTYPE
BTypeNext = '00';
BranchTo(target, BranchType_RET, FALSE);
```

Comment: Does it imply that the godbolt link that compiles 192-bit integer addition shows that LLVM 14.0 is buggy?

Comment: @aqjune what makes you think that?

Comment: Its last instruction before `ret` is `adcs`, not `adc`. This will set the carry flag if subtraction underflows.

Comment: Note that in LLVM 15.0 the last instruction is now `adc`: https://godbolt.org/z/crj3WKP1G .

Comment: @aqjune the codegen isn't optimal, but I wouldn't classify that as a bug.